# How to export from one Server to another Server Database table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to move data from one server database to another server database.
I hope the following code will work.
But I don't know what is my `DestinationServerName` and `SourceServerName`. Where I can find those names.

```
INSERT INTO [DestinationServerName].[DatabaseName1].[dbo].[TableName]

SELECT  
    [FieldName] 
FROM 
    [SourceServerName].[DatabaseName2].[dbo].[TableName]
```

Comment: Using SQL Server Export / Import wizard .

Comment: your query will work id both Db are on same server and you have permission to use it . The best way to to use Wizard mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In [4 parts name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx) `Servername` is a name given to a [linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(v=sql.110).aspx). You may create linked servers with SSMS or by using [sp_addlinkedserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)